# XPath data after closing tag

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I have this HTML:
`<span id="bla">text</span>more text`

I want to get `text` and `more text`.

I have this XPath:
`//span[@id="bla"]/text()`

I can't figure out how to get the closing tag and what comes after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span id="bla">text</span>more text` alone is not well-formed and cannot be processed via XPath.

Let's put it in context:

```
<div><span id="bla">text</span>more text</div>
```

Then, you can simply take the string value of the parent element, `div`:

```
string(/div)
```

to get

```
textmore text
```

as requested.

---

If there's other surrounding content that you *don't* want:

```
<div>DO NOT WANT<span id="bla">text</span>more text<b/>DO NOT WANT</div>
```

You can follow @alecxe's lead with the `following-sibling::` axis and use `concat()` to combine the parts you want:

```
concat(//span[@id="bla"], //span[@id="bla"]/following-sibling::text()[1])
```

to again get

```
textmore text
```

as requested.

Answer (score 2):

The `more text` is called a "tail" of an element and can be retrieved via [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//span[@id="bla"]/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: Can I get them both in the same query?

Comment: @Lior: Yes, [using `string()` on the parent element or `concat()` on the individual parts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38778815/290085).